# knitr, rmarkdown, to powerpoint - mix text and table on two content or two column slide

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, flextable, officer

#### My goal

My goal consists in knitting a table plus text next to each other to powerpoint (think: we want an explanation text or callout with our table). I want to do this from within markdown and using knitr/rmarkdown and/or the officer package.

Is this possible?

#### Attempt

The following .Rmd does **NOT** result in table next to text:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  officedown::rpptx_document
---

```{r, setup, echo=0, warning=0, message=0}
pacman::p_load(officer, flextable)
```

## Test

This should appear left

```{r, layout = "Two Content", ph=officer::ph_location_right(), echo=0}
flextable(head(mtcars))
```
````

#### Resulting ppt output (not desired)

[image: knitr powerpoint table and text]

#### This is the desired output

[image: knitr powerpoint table and text two content]

#### What else I tried

- Columns in rmarkdown (does not do the trick)

#### SessionInfo

- R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
- officer_0.6.2
- flextable_0.9.2